# Skype Web SDK can't sign in

Tags: angular, skypedeveloper

I'm following the MSDN guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/developwebsdkappsforsfbonline) to sign in from an Angular app to Skype Online.

Still, the client can't sign in, I get
`cannot sign in Error: GET https://webdir2e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user failed: Unauthorized`

The same user and the same appId works within the Skype SDK web [sample](https://ucwa.skype.com/), so the issue can't be with Azure AD permissions.

It's very suspicious that as the app makes GET requests to `https://webdir2e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user`, I see that the **Authorization header is flawed**, as it shows as:
`Authorization: undefined undefined`

**Note** that the app uses ADAL to access the Graph API - which works flawless.

My index.html contains the following code, basically copy & pasted from the guide and replaced the client_id:

```
<script src="https://swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.2.35/SkypeBootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var config = {
      apiKey: '595a1aeb-e6dc-4e5b-be96-bb38adc83da1', // SDK
      apiKeyCC: '08c97289-7d57-404f-bd97-a6047403e370' // SDK+UI
    };
    var Application;
    var client_id = 'xxx';

    var hasToken = /^#access_token=/.test(location.hash);
    var hasError = /^#error=/.test(location.hash);

    // redirect to Org ID if there is no token in the URL
    if (!hasToken && !hasError) {
      location.assign('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token' +
        '&client_id=' + client_id +
        '&redirect_uri=' + location.href +
        '&resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com');
    }

    // show the UI if the user has signed in
    if (hasToken) {
      Skype.initialize({
        apiKey: config.apiKey,
        correlationIds: {
          sessionId: 'mySession123', // Necessary for troubleshooting requests, should be unique per session
        }
      }, function (api) {
        app = new api.application();
        // the SDK will get its own access token
        app.signInManager.signIn({
          client_id: client_id,
          cors: true,
          redirect_uri: '/an/empty/page/for/ie.html',
          origins: ["https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root"],
          version: 'meeting-scheduler/0.1' // Necessary for troubleshooting requests; identifies your application in our telemetry
        }).then(() => {
          console.log("signed in as", app.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.displayName());
        }, err => {
          console.log("cannot sign in", err);
        });;
      });
    }

    if (hasError) {
      console.log(location.hash);
    }
```